# Imagenes aleatorias por row - PHP

Tags: php

Me encuentro con la siguiente duda, resulta que tengo un formulario de inscripción de cursos, donde tengo un codigo para mostrar los cursos disponibles desde la BD, y cada columna la muestra con una imagen de fondo al azar,

```html
<?php
 $imagenes[0]='images/cursos/cursoX1.jpg';
 $imagenes[1]='images/cursos/cursoX2.jpg';
 $imagenes[2]='images/cursos/cursoX3.jpg';
 $imagenes[3]='images/cursos/cursoX4.jpg';
 $imagenes[4]='images/cursos/cursoX5.jpg';
 $i=rand(0,4);    
   $conex=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","capacitaciones");
   $utf8=mysqli_query($conex, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 $result = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT nombre_curso, id_curso from cursos where disponible='si'");
      if($result)
      {
          while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){  
  echo"
  
   <div class='container-fluid proj-bottom'>
   <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8 col-sm-6 fh5co-project animate-box' data-animate-effect='fadeIn' style='margin-left: 300px'>
    
     <a href='#'><img src='$imagenes[$i]' alt='' class='img-responsive'>
      <h3><b>CURSO DISPONIBLE - $registro->nombre_curso</b></h3>
     </a>
     <br>
     <form action='cursos/curso1.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form_curso' target='_self' id='form_curso'>
     <input type='hidden' name='id_curso' id='id_curso' value='$registro->id_curso'>
     <input name='nombre_curso' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' type='submit' value='$registro->nombre_curso' id='nombre_curso' /> 
    </form> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

    ";  }
 } ?>
```

El detalle esta en que cada row me lo muestra con la misma imagen, y lo que deseo es que cada row me lo muestre con una imagen diferente, ¿como puedo lograr eso?,

Saludos y muchas gracias,

Comment: Pon el $i=rand(0,4); encima del echo para que en cada vuelta, cambie su valor.

Comment: Te pasaste, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Algo así por si algún día agregas más cursos y no dependas del tamaño del rand, sino del tamaño de tu arreglo `$imagenes` (elimine la conexión a bd y sus resultados en el codigo para poder probarlo solo con el html generado):

```
<?php
$imagenes[0]='images/cursos/cursoX1.jpg';
$imagenes[1]='images/cursos/cursoX2.jpg';
$imagenes[2]='images/cursos/cursoX3.jpg';
$imagenes[3]='images/cursos/cursoX4.jpg';
$imagenes[4]='images/cursos/cursoX5.jpg';
$i=0;       

 while($i < count($imagenes)){  
    echo"

        <div class='container-fluid proj-bottom'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-8 col-sm-6 fh5co-project animate-box' data-animate-effect='fadeIn' style='margin-left: 300px'>

                <a href='#'><img src='$imagenes[$i]' alt='' class='img-responsive'>
                    <h3><b>CURSO DISPONIBLE [$i]</b></h3>
                </a>
             </div>

         "; 
  $i = $i + 1;

}
```

El html que resulta es algo como esto:

[image: Lo generado por html es lo siguiente]